# List All User Accounts on a Windows System via Command Line

Tags: windows, command-line, user-accounts

I would like a command to list all of the user accounts in a Windows (Vista, 7, etc.) system in a way that I can use to iterate through them with a subsequent command.

`net user` gives me the data for which I'm searching, but it adds a bunch of other junk that would cause difficulty in parsing the users.

Ideally, I would receive output like:

```
> usercommand
user1
user2
user3
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to iterate through users strictly in the Windows command line, the easiest way would be a combination of `wmic` and a `for` loop.

```
for /f "tokens=* skip=1" %%a in ('wmic UserAccount get Name') do (
    if not "%%a"=="" (
        :: %%a is a variable containing an account name
    )
)
```

The heart of the command is `wmic UserAccount get Name`, which should print out a list of accounts. You may wish to do some filtering, like Karan did in his VBScript answer, with something like `wmic UserAccount where "LocalAccount=True" get Name`. Any field is filterable; to view all of them, use `wmic UserAccount get` (omitting `Name`).

The `for` loop is simply used to parse the command output. It skips the first line (which prints the column heading), and the last line is skipped with the `if` command, since it is empty. See `for /?` for more information.

Comment: Beware that if you're in a domain (at least in a Samba domain, don't know about Windows AD), `wmic` will also list all domain accounts which might not be what you want, and also takes quite some time. `wmic useraccount where "localaccount=true" get name` prevents this.

Answer (score 13):

For anyone who is here just looking for a way to list all users on your machine in the command line, and don't need a loop.  Just run this command:

```
net user
```

And it will output what you need in this format

```
-------------------------------------
User1    User2    User3    User4
The command completed successfully.
```

Comment: This info is already in the question.

Comment: That's true, but I put it here for all of the people that were scrolling straight to the answers.  It's a common question, and this was the number one search result for how to list all users on a machine in the command line at the time I wrote it.  Reading the questions is important though.

Answer (score 0):

This **Windows PowerShell** script will provide a list of users in a table format, it's not exactly what you are looking for but it shouldn't be too hard to reformat the output into a format you could use to feed into another command.

```
$computerName = "$env:computername"
$computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computerName,computer" 
$computer.psbase.Children | Where-Object { $_.psbase.schemaclassname -eq 'user' } | Format-Table Name, Description -autoSize
```

Comment: Inspired by this script: http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/2327.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. Save the following with a name like **GetLocalUsers.vbs**:

   ```
   Set colItems = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_UserAccount Where LocalAccount=True")
   For Each objItem in colItems
       Wscript.Echo objItem.Name
   Next
   ```
2. Run from the command line as follows:

   ```
   cscript //NoLogo GetLocalUsers.vbs
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This will output literally what you're asking for:

dir /b C:\Users

Comment: That will fail to list any accounts that have not yet logged into the particular machine.